# Jailbreak tweak to enable split-screen multitasking on iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad-app

I'm looking for a jailbreak tweak that allows for having two apps run side-by-side. I find it useful to take notes on a document on the other side.

I'm currently using [ReachApp](http://ioshacker.com/how-to/use-reachapp-or-reachability-tweaks-on-non-touch-id-devices), but that has some problems.

- Using some features of some apps cause the iPad to reboot to Safe Mode
- The hardware keyboard doesn't work in apps updated for iOS 9, or Google Docs.
- Often you can't scroll to the bottom of an app

Though iOS 9 has a Split Screen feature, it's not available for my iPad, the iPad Air.

Requirements:

- Not too buggy
- Compatible with iOS 8
- Software keyboard is in the right place (like not in the top app)
- Easy to split the screen (i.e., not just windows à la pre-El Capitan OS X)

Nice-to-haves:

- Split in both portrait and landscape
- Open multiple windows of the same app (is that even possible?)

Answer (score 2):

Well there are a lot of multitasking tweaks out there you can use. i will list a couple of them below and see what fits you right.

> - The first tweak i liked is **multiplexer**.The tweak blends traditional side-by-side multitasking options along with enhanced
>     backgrounding, and multiple desktops., Multiplexer is a legit six
>     tweaks in one. Each of the parts that make up Multiplexer contain a
>     separate preference panel inside of Multiplexer’s preferences. They
>     are as follows:
>
> **Aura** – Lets apps run in the background
>   **Empoleon** – Windowed multitasking
>   **Mission Control** – Manage multiple desktops and their windows
>   **Quick Access** – Have an app in Notification Center
>   **Reach App** – Use and app in Reachability alongside another
>   **Swipe Over** – Access another app simply by swiping in from the right side of the screen

[Here is the Link for the video](https://youtu.be/oF7PMn_ffF0)

-

> Another one you can use is **multify**.The real impressive feature is
>   Multify’s edit mode. As stated, edit mode is what allows you to move
>   and resize apps. This lets you run multiple apps side-by-side on
>   screen at once. For example, you can have a YouTube video playing
>   while browsing Tweetbot and reading Reddit. It’s powerful stuff.

[Here is the Link for the video](https://youtu.be/1B5p8suSBqA)

-

> Another one you can use is  **SideBySide**.The tweak would bring true
>   side-by-side simultaneous multitasking to iPads and iPhone, and would
>   use Activator gestures as a means of invocation.To me, the fluidity of
>   SideBySide looks like it could give ReachApp a run for its money. I
>   also like the fact that it uses Activator, and doesn’t rely on
>   Reachability, which limits how the tweak can be invoked.*Sorry i
>   couldn't post a link to this one because of the low reputation*